# how to get substring using regular expression in java?

Tags: java, regex

```
String str = "#aaa# #bbb# #ccc#   #ddd#"
```

Can anybody tell me how can i get the substrings “aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd" (substring which is in the pair of "# #" and the number of "# #" is unknown) using regular expression?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#(\\w+)#");
String input = "#aaa# #bbb# #ccc#   #ddd#";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>();
while (m.find())
{
    parts.add(m.group(1));
}

// parts is [aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd]
```

http://ideone.com/i1IAZ

Comment: yeah that works=). Would you please explain to me what does "w+" mean in the regex? Thanks =)

Comment: It's standard regex syntax. Read [the JavaDocs linked in my answer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). If those aren't clear enough, acquaint yourself with http://regular-expressions.info.

Comment: hmm if i change the input String into "#aaa# #bbb bbb# #ccc#   #ddd#", then the parts will be [aaa,null,ccc,ddd]. Can you figure out a more general way that "bbb bbb"(there is a space between the words in the substring) can also be output? Thanks a lot =D

Comment: Change `(\\w+)` to `([\\w\\s]+)` or `([^#]+)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String str = "1aaa2 3bbb4 5ccc6   7ddd8";
String[] data = str.split("[\\d ]+");
```

Each position in the resulting array will contain a substring, except the first one which is empty:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
> [, aaa, bbb, ccc, ddd]
```

Comment: ... or something like that.  As with so many questions on regexes, the OP has not CLEARLY specified his/her requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Here is yet another way of doing it using `StringTokenizer`

```
    String str="#aaa# #bbb# #ccc#   #ddd#";
    //# and space are the delimiters
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, "# ");
    List<String> parts = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
       parts.add(tokenizer.nextToken());
```

Comment: -1. _"`StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the `split` method of `String` or the java.util.regex package instead."_ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html

Comment: ok. I see your point. Though it's available in Java 7(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), this class won't be available in future releases? got my answer in your comment update :-)